# Can this Runnable cause a memory leak, when app is closed?

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, ui-thread

I have this piece of code in my `onViewCreated` to request focus on my `EditText` .

```
someEditText.apply { post { requestFocus() } }
```

Let's say that the app is closed before that `Runnable` completes.

Is it possible to create a memory leak in such scenario and if so, how should I solve it?

Comment: No, you're posting it to the main thread and your Activity will get an `onDestroy` call on the main thread before it's gone.